# Multiple directives on same page execute all at once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've built a directive to create a toggle menu and I have problem with it when using the same diretive multiple times on the same page.

This is the directive:

```
function menuTrigger($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var
                menuOpen    = false,
                elButton    = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".menu-button")),
                elContent   = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".menu-content")),
                elClose     = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("[menu-close]"));

            var
                pos = attrs.pos,
                style;

            if (pos == 'tl') {
                style = {top: '0', left: '0', 'transform-origin': 'top left'}
            } else if (pos == 'tr') {
                style = {top: '0', right: '0', 'transform-origin': 'top right'}
            } else if (pos == 'bl') {
                style = {bottom: '0', left: '0', 'transform-origin': 'bottom left'}
            } else if (pos == 'br') {
                style = {bottom: '0', right: '0', 'transform-origin': 'bottom right'}
            };


            element.bind('click', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                openMenu();
            });
            elClose.bind('click', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                closeMenu();
            });
            $document.on('click', function () {
                if (menuOpen == true) {
                    closeMenu();
                };
            });

            function openMenu() {
                menuOpen = true;
                elContent.removeClass('menu-hide');
                elContent.css(style);
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    elContent.addClass('menu-open');
                }, 100);
            };
            function closeMenu() {
                menuOpen = false;
                elContent.removeClass('menu-open');
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    elContent.addClass('menu-hide');
                    elContent.removeAttr('style');
                }, 400);
            };
        }
    };
}
```

So, for example, if I'm using 1 menu on a main view, let's say the top navbar and then in a sub view I have other menu to control a selection, when I click on one menu, both of them will open.

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: I stopped looking for a solution when I saw all the querySelectorAll, element.bind and removeClass (jQuery) code. I think that is your problem. Your not doing Angular.

Comment: Ok, but then.. any suggestions? I'm new to it.

Comment: Well, it'll become a long story but basicallly you want to use ng-class to handle adding and removing classes inside your template, ng-click to handle clicks and child directives that communicate with your parent directive by requiring them instead of the querySelector approach. Lot's to learn I guess ;)

Comment: I know how to use `ng-class`, `ng-click`, etc.. The only 'new thing' is the "child directives that communicate with your parent directive by requiring them". I just didn't knew how to put this all together within a directive. But you mean to be something like: `scope.openMenu = function() {scope.menuopen = true};` and then `ng-class="{'open': menuopen}` This logic?

Comment: Yes, and you can require parent directive controllers with the require: 'myParentDirective' property on the directive definition. You get the controller instance injected in as 4th argument to the link function.

Comment: Can you show me an example of this require @BasSlagter ?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested an example on how to require parent directive controllers. That should enable you to use less jQuery style code.

```
myModule.directive('myParentDirective', function(){
    return {
       controller: function(){
           var vm = this;
           vm.foo = 'bar';
       }
    };
});

myModule.directive('myChildDirective', function(){
    return {
       require: 'myParentDirective',
       link: function(scope, elem, attrs, parentController){
           console.log(parentController.foo); // equals 'bar'
       }
    };
});

<my-parent-directive>
    <my-child-directive></my-child-directive
</my-parent-directive>
```

Comment: Didn't had to make this nested directives, just by moving to a ng-click/ng-class system it all worked very well. Also, the code is better and shorter. Thanks for the tips, I knew about these process, but didn't knew how to put it together. Only one thing.. I had to use scope.apply to make the change on the scope value to validate the ng-class. Is it a good practice? Because i've read some articles about avoiding this.

Comment: You should indeed avoid $scope.$apply and $scope.$digest but it might be needed in your case if you do things outside the digest loop.

Comment: Yes, I read something about it, also, this is why at first I was trying to avoid the use of scope. My app now is a very complex app with a lot of data and it was getting laggy. Is there a way to use $apply to a single scope value? I didn't found anything about it. Or ever $apply will run $digest?

Comment: Yes, $apply triggers a digest. You shouldn't avoid using scope (its how Angular works). At best you can go with the controllerAs approach. If you do things more the Angular way you will see you need less digest and/or apply calls since Angular will keep track of changes for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're binding multiple times to multiple elements on your page:

```
// This will be an array of elements that will match the class .menu-button.
// Not just the .menu-button element within your directive.
// Try typing it in your browser developer tools console to see what I mean.

angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".menu-button"))
```

If you really want to grab the individual elements from within the directive, you'll need to locate them like this:

```
// Use the element argument from the link function 
angular.element(element[0].querySelectorAll(".menu-button"));
```

But -- in most cases it's easier (and more elegant) to use `ng-click`, `ng-class` directives and such. Just create your click handlers on the `scope` object in the directive `link` function and wire them in the html markup.

```
scope.myClickHandler = function() {
  // Magic goes here
};

<div my-directive ng-click="myClickHandler"></div>
```

Hope this helps.